# Split word from string using PHP

Tags: php

I tried to split the characters from the available string, but have not found the right way.

I have a string like below :

```
$tara = 'wordpress/corporate/business';
$k = explode('/', $tara);
foreach ($k as $l) {
    var_dump(substr_replace($tara, '', $i, count($l)));
}
```

The result I want is :

```
'wordpress',
'wordpress/corporate',
'wordpress/corporate/business'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could concatenate in every iteration like :

```
$tara = 'wordpress/corporate/business';
$k = explode('/', $tara);
$result = "";

foreach ($k as $l) {
    $result .= '/'.$l;
    echo $result."<br>";
}
```

The output will be :

> /wordpress
>   /wordpress/corporate
>   /wordpress/corporate/business

If you don't need the slashes at the start you could add a condition like :

```
$tara = 'wordpress/corporate/business';
$k = explode('/', $tara);
$result = "";

foreach ($k as $l) 
{
    if( empty($result) ){
        echo $l."<br>";
        $result = $l;
    }else{
        $result .= '/'.$l;
        echo $result."<br>";
    }
}
```

Or using the shortened version inside loop with ternary operation, like :

```
foreach ($k as $l) 
{
    $result .= empty($result) ? $l : '/'.$l;
    echo $result."<br>";
}
```

The output will be :

> wordpress
>   wordpress/corporate
>   wordpress/corporate/business

Comment: @SiskaBrilian : do you want `/` in start ?

Comment: @SiskaBrilian Please read the placeholder text on the comment boxes under the answers -- Avoid saying "thanks" or "+1"  Please delete your comments.

Answer (score 2):

How about constructing the results from the array alements:

```
$tara = 'wordpress/corporate/business';
$k = explode('/', $tara);

$s = '';
foreach ($k as $l) {
    $s .= ($s != '' ? '/' : '') . $l;
    var_dump($s);
}
```

This results in:

> string(9) "wordpress"
>
> string(19) "wordpress/corporate"
>
> string(28) "wordpress/corporate/business"

Answer (score 1):

You should explode your string array and print in foreach all exploded values using implode and temporary array(for example). Here is working code:

```
$tara = 'wordpress/corporate/business';
$k = explode('/', $tara);
$tmp = [];

foreach ($k as $l) {
    $tmp[] .= $l;
    var_dump(implode($tmp, '/'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create new array and inside foreach

```
<?php
$tara = 'wordpress/corporate/business';
$url = array();
foreach(explode("/",$tara) as $val){
  $url[] = $val;
  echo implode("/",$url)."\n";  
}
?>
```

Demo : https://eval.in/932527

Output is

```
wordpress
wordpress/corporate
wordpress/corporate/business
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This, Its Easiest :**

```
$tara = 'wordpress/corporate/business';
$k = explode('/', $tara);
$str = array();
foreach ($k as $l) {
   $str[] = $l;
   echo implode('/',$str)."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low-value on StackOverflow. Please ALWAYS post an explanation with every answer.

Comment: Sure @mickmackusa

Comment: ...well, are you actually going to fix up your post?  Click on `edit` under your answer.